# what is the best way to multiply tensors in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose that I have tensors `x[i,j,k]` and `y[p,q]` in a graph. What is the correct way to specify the tensor `z[i,j,k,p,q] = x[i,j,k]y[p,q]`? This is the coordinate representation of the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of `x` and `y`. I can get the job done using a combination of `tf.expand_dims`, `tf.mult` and  `tf.tile`, but I feel like there should be a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get away without the tile operation using broadcasting.

```
x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, (i, j, k, 1, 1))
y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, (1, 1, 1, p, q))
z = x_reshaped * y_reshaped
```

When a dimension has size 1 and does not match the size of the other tensor's dimensions it is being multiplied with, it is copied / broadcasted automatically along that dimension and the product is carried out.  Tile is often unnecessary.  I actually don't think I have ever even used tile in tensorflow.  Here I also used reshape rather than expand_dims but the result is the same either way.